# Device or resource busy with Sagemaker and S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I've been trying to download some json data from my bucket, as usual, on my SageMaker instance.
Out of nowhere, this error started showing up.

```
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: 'transcript_data/..Aea2DBEA' -> 'transcript_data/.'
```

I don't understand how to solve this, since I already tried restarting the instances, but it didn't help much.

Also, I tried changing from one kernel to the other (pytorch and conda python), but it didn't help.

Here is my code snippet for downloading files:

```
LOCAL_PATH = "transcript_data/"
files = sagemaker_session.list_s3_files(bucket, FOLDER_PREFIX)
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.json'):
        sagemaker_session.download_data(path=LOCAL_PATH, bucket=bucket, key_prefix=FOLDER_PREFIX)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that with SageMaker Studio Notebooks? You seem to have a disk issue.  Verify by trying to download to /tmp instead to bypass the share storage (based on EFS)